# mono on debian: Could not find file "/srv/www/proj/bin\roslyn\csc.exe"

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, mono

I try to deploy a ASP NET 4.5 Website written in Visual Studio to a Mono Server.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Could not find file "/srv/www/proj/bin\roslyn\csc.exe".

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Could not find file "/srv/www/proj/bin\roslyn\csc.exe".

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): mscorlib.
Exception stack trace:
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) <0x41aaab70 + 0x006e7> in     <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) <0x41bba470 + 0x00053> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) <0x41bc4b50 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.get_CompilerName () <0x41e0fb40 + 0x00086> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.FromFileBatch (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) <0x41e1d600 + 0x005ce> in     <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) <0x41e1d460 +     0x000c7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) <0x41e1d2b0 + 0x0004d> in <filename     unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath, System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options) <0x41e0da40 + 0x00991> in <filename     unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) <0x41e0da00 + 0x00023> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GenerateAssembly (System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder abuilder, System.Web.Compilation.BuildProviderGroup group, System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean     debug) <0x41e0be60 + 0x009af> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BuildInner (System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) <0x41dc8e90 + 0x00523> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Build (System.Web.VirtualPath vp) <0x41dc89d0 + 0x0011b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) <0x41dc87f0 + 0x00093> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.String virtualPath) <0x41dc87c0 + 0x00017> in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.String virtualPath) <0x41dc87a0 + 0x00013> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render (System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext viewContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer) <0x41dc8580 + 0x00055> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context) <0x41dbb2a0 + 0x001ec> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) <0x41d3a2f0 + 0x0001d> in     <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive (IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext,     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) <0x41dbae00 + 0x0008a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive (IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext,     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) <0x41dbae00 + 0x001bf> in <filename unknown>:0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I managed it to work.
For those, who are searching for a similar solution:

In my Apache vHost Configuration I need to add

```
MonoSetEnv inventur.netdienste.com MONO_IOMAP=all
```

That directive translated the forward slashes to backward slashes.

Comment: This also fixed the issue for me when running from MonoDevelop. Launching it as `MONO_IOMAP=all monodevelop` worked.

Comment: I'm working on OS Sierra and just only have installed VS. Where should I put this line? Could you explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is what's causing your problem but you have some incorrectly facing slants in your path string.

It is either:

```
"/srv/www/proj/bin/roslyn/csc.exe"
```

Or:

```
"\srv\www\proj\bin\roslyn\csc.exe"
```

Comment: Where can I change this path setting? I didn't find it,

Comment: @DanielPomrehn I just assumed you had a string incorrectly typed in your source code somewhere, although the exception is not helping tell where.