# VS on macOS: Could not find file /bin\roslyn\csc.exe". Path issue

Tags: asp.net, macos, mono, roslyn, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to get the MS Bot builder samples up and running on a mac, using VS Preview. Every time I try to run the application I get an error 500 and:

> ```
> Could not find file "/Users/*****/BotBuilder-master/CSharp/Samples/PizzaBot/bin\roslyn\csc.exe".
> ```

The CSC is located in the expected location, but the path is obviously wrong.
I found this SO post with a similar issue [mono on debian: Could not find file "/srv/www/proj/bin\roslyn\csc.exe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777551/mono-on-debian-could-not-find-file-srv-www-proj-bin-roslyn-csc-exe)
But since I'm running the code from VS, I can't just modify the Apache server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's why it is still a preview. MSBuild on non-Windows is not yet ready to serve such tasks.

Comment: @lexLi I'm aware it's still in preview. According to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777551/mono-on-debian-could-not-find-file-srv-www-proj-bin-roslyn-csc-exe it should be possible to get up and running on Debian. I guess it should be possible on mac as well, with some tweaking or working-arounding. That's what this question is about.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the project form https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/. Then I opened the Microsoft.Bot.Sample.PizzaBot.csproj file and removed lines 168 and 169 (because the looked quite VS for windows paths)

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
```

Then I opened VS For Mac, set PizzaBot as default project and it worked as expected.